# How to override JAX-WS web service endpoint defined with @WebService and @Staless?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jax-ws

I have class annotated with @WebService and @Stateless as shown in the snippet below.

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class BookManagerService implements BookManager{
// Body
}
```

I would like to know what is the specification which defines on which endpoint this web service will be deployed by default. Is there any JAX-WS provider independent mechanism to override this default endpoint?

EDIT: Default pattern on WebLogic for example is the following:

```
http(s)://<server.hostname>:<server.port>/<className>/<className>Service
```

I would like to be able to override everything after:

```
http(s)://<server.hostname>:<server.port>/
```

I am also wondering if this endpoint format is standard (and therefore where it is defined) or it is JAX-WS provider specific.

Answer (score 0):

The Java API for XML Web Services (JAX-WS) specification can be downloaded here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/webservices-139501.html

Also relevant is JSR 181, Web Services Metadata for the Java Platform, which can be downloaded from the same page. It includes the complete spec for the WebService annotation.

Overriding defaults is possible with @WebService annotation attributes, they are documented here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jws/WebService.html

Example:

http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-webservice/README.html

Comment: I don't think it helps me for my specific case :). I know I can override stuff with the annotation but the problem is to override the endpoint! I don't care about the WSDL location part :).

Comment: @Abbadon can you edit your question and show an example of your actual endpoint and the desired endpoint value?

Answer (score 0):

I dont't understand the question. An endpoint is a URL like this:

http://server:port/appContext/ws-servlet-url/ws-name

- The server and port are defined by the app server where you are deploying.
- The appContext and the webservice servlet url pattern are defined in the web.xml. You also can change the appContext when deploy.
- The webservice name is the name of the Class or the value you choose with the serviceName annotation.

What are the values you want to override?

Comment: This may be true for web service which are not stateless session beans but for web services annotated with @ WebService and @ Stateless, on WebLogic at least, the default pattern is the following:
http(s)://<server.hostname>:<server.port>/<className>/<className>Service